# How to handle step function if output is empty when i run Describe API

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, automation, aws-step-functions

I am trying to Describe Volume using step function whenever the volume state is in the available state
ill run parallel step to delete the volume and send SNS
but if no volume is in the available state it should go end state.

**Output when there is no Volume with available state found**

```
{
  "Volumes": {
    "Volumes": []
  }
}
```

**Output when volume with available state found**

```
{
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "Attachments": [],
      "AvailabilityZone": "ap-south-1a",
      "CreateTime": "2023-09-01T07:18:09.515Z",
      "Encrypted": false,
      "Iops": 300,
      "MultiAttachEnabled": false,
      "Size": 100,
      "SnapshotId": "",
      "State": "available",
      "VolumeId": "vol-123456707eb0c",
      "VolumeType": "gp2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm passing that into the if condition If it's empty like above it should exit
but it proceeds with the default condition

**If condition code**

```
"CheckVolumes": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.Volumes",
          "StringEquals": "[]",
          "Next": "EndState"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "ProcessVolumes"
    }
```

**My step function code**

```
{
  "Comment": "A modified version of the Step Functions code",
  "StartAt": "DescribeVolumes",
  "States": {
    "DescribeVolumes": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:ec2:describeVolumes",
      "Parameters": {
        "Filters": [
          {
            "Name": "status",
            "Values": [
              "available"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.Volumes",
      "Next": "CheckVolumes"
    },
    "CheckVolumes": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.Volumes",
          "StringEquals": "[]",
          "Next": "EndState"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "ProcessVolumes"
    },
    "ProcessVolumes": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "End": true,
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "Map",
          "States": {
            "Map": {
              "Type": "Map",
              "ItemsPath": "$.Volumes.Volumes",
              "Iterator": {
                "StartAt": "DeleteVolume",
                "States": {
                  "DeleteVolume": {
                    "Type": "Task",
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:ec2:deleteVolume",
                    "Parameters": {
                      "VolumeId.$": "$.VolumeId"
                    },
                    "End": true
                  }
                }
              },
              "End": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "StartAt": "SNS Publish",
          "States": {
            "SNS Publish": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sns:publish",
              "Parameters": {
                "Message": "Below are the Volumes which are not attached to any instance and in available state",
                "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:123456789012:test"
              },
              "End": true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "EndState": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

I tried all possible ways like below

```
$.Volumes.Volumes == []
$.Volumes.Volumes.length == 0
$.Volumes == null
$.Volumes == empty
```

Below is the **Graph view**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Choice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html) state provides comparison operators for scalar types, but not for array-type values.  The string `"[]"` does not equal an empty array `[]`, so your condition is never met.

One way to solve your problem is to redefine your Choice state to branch on a volume count condition: exit early if the number of volumes equals zero.

How do we get the number of volumes?  Add a ResultSelector to the DescribeVolumes task to reshape its result. The `ArrayLength` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-arrays) can do the counting:

```json
"ResultSelector": {
  "volumes.$": "$.Volumes",
  "count.$": "States.ArrayLength($.Volumes)"
}
```

If the task returns volumes, the output will look like:

```json
{
  "volumes": [
    {
      "Attachments": [],
      "AvailabilityZone": "ap-south-1a",
      "CreateTime": "2023-09-01T07:18:09.515Z",
      "Encrypted": false,
      "Iops": 300,
      "MultiAttachEnabled": false,
      "Size": 100,
      "SnapshotId": "",
      "State": "available",
      "VolumeId": "vol-123456707eb0c",
      "VolumeType": "gp2"
    }
  ],
  "count": 1
}
```

If there are no volumes, the output will look like:

```json
{
  "volumes": [],
  "count": 0
}
```

Your Choice state can now apply a `"NumericEquals": 0,` condition to the `$.Volumes.count` path.